# How do you do this "location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; }" in Apache2?

Tags: apache, nginx

I found a workaround for a permalink issue on Wordpress but its for nginx and i couldnt find any way to do it in apache2.

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;}
```

Does someone know how to do it in apache?

Answer (score 0):

nginx doesn't support htaccess rules so you should configure web server like so, but Apache web server supports htaccess rules. you can check your .htaccess file and edit it as bellow:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Although it should be done automatically when you install wordpress.

If your htaccess content is Ok but the Permalinks are not Ok please check in terminal and make sure you have enabled mod_rewrite in apache:

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

Check your virtualhost configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ and make sure that it is configured with `AllowOverride All` instead of the default `AllowOverride None` for your web root directory.

Comment: Thanks it works now !
If anyone gets this problem, the part fixing it was changing AllowOverride to All in  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf